# count similar attribute value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working (practice) on a Data Set with below table structure. I have developed different queries and have been successful so far. However, two queries are troubling me and was wondering if you guys could point what I am doing wrong.

1: Need to extract top 10 AuthorAccountId that created the highest number of changes on the project 'abc'.

e.g returns the top 10 AuthorAccountId that created the highest number of changes on the project 'abc'. The query must return two columns: the authorId and the number of changes made each author.

Following is the query that I have developed but does not give me the desired result.

```
SELECT ch_authoraccountid,count(ch_project)
FROM t_change 
WHERE ch_project LIKE 'abc' 
ORDER BY ch_authoraccountId DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

2: Return the names of authors who did not submit any change during the year 2017, ( this one is going to be sub query on t_change).

e.g Expected result should return the name of authors who did not bring any changes in the year 2017.

Following is the query

```
SELECT p_name 
FROM t_people 
WHERE p_accountid IN (SELECT ch_createdTime 
                      FROM t_change 
                      WHERE ch_createdTime != '2016-01-01')")
```

Ref : Yang, R. G. Kula, N. Yoshida and H. Iida, "Mining the Modern Code Review Repositories: A Dataset of People, Process and Product," 2016 IEEE/ACM 13th Working Conference on Mining SoftwareRepositories (MSR), Austin, TX, 2016, pp. 
460-463.

https://github.com/kin-y/miningReviewRepo/wiki/Database-Schema

[image: ER diagram]

Comment: Why LIKE = 'abc' instead of = 'abc' ? The second query is not ok too ? What are yours expected result and actual result ?

Comment: @Arnaud Peralta, I included the expected result in the question.

Answer (score 1):

For the first query, try this :

```
SELECT ch_authoraccountid, COUNT(ch_project)
FROM t_change 
WHERE ch_project = 'abc' 
GROUP BY ch_authoraccountid
ORDER BY COUNT(ch_project) DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

It will count the number of change in 'abc' project per authoraccountid.

For the second :

```
SELECT p_name 
FROM t_people 
WHERE p_accountid NOT IN (SELECT ch_authorAccountId 
                          FROM t_change 
                          WHERE ch_createdTime BETWEEN '20170101' AND '20171231')")
```